# Why my animation does not stop in the right point?

Tags: android, animation, slide, ontouchlistener

In may app, I have two animations. One is growing from the bottom to the top of the screen. It is called inside my startNewAnimation() method:

```
mSurfaceGrowingAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, mViewHeight, 0);
mSurfaceGrowingAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

This method is called inside this one:

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = ViewTimer.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onGlobalLayout");
        mViewHeight = ViewTimer.getHeight();
        startNewAnimation();
        ViewTimer.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }
});
```

My other animation works like a slide button. It is used to stop the animation.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        showDialog();
        pauseAnimation();
        int endOfAnimation = findViewById(R.id.slide_included).getWidth() - mSlideView.getWidth();
        mSlideAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(event.getX(), endOfAnimation - layoutParams.x, 0, 0);
        mSlideAnimation.setDuration(1000);          
        mSlideAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        mSlideView.startAnimation(mSlideAnimation);

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        layoutParams.x = (int) event.getRawX();
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        break;
    }
```

That is, when I move the slide view, I call the pauseAnimation() method which clear the main animation.

The problem is: When my main animation stops, if it is below the slide button, then it is painted until the top of the slide view. How can I fix this?

This is my layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frame_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/time_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/surface_view_timer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:background="#77B21B00" /> 
    </RelativeLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/slide_included"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    layout="@layout/slide" />

</FrameLayout>
```

slide.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/slide_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="#0000FF" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/slide_to_pause"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#00FFFF" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```